# Why is the Route Value not passed to MVC controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here I'm iterating through Products in my ViewModel:

```
@foreach (var p in Model.Products)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("ProductSummary", p);
    <p>@Html.ActionLink("Details...", "Details", "Product", new { p.ProductID }, null)</p>
}
```

Here is my Details action in ProductController:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 1)
{
    return View();
}
```

`id` always has a default value = 1, but I need the chosen `ProductID`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

`new { p.ProductID }` will create an anonymous type with a `ProductID` property.

The route values have to match, so use `new { id = p.ProductID }` to populate your `id` parameter.